# Into A Bottle Of Wine

Tags: meaning, usage

On google, I found sentences using the preposition "*into*" like this:

> 1. He was halfway ***into*** a bottle of wine.

Could sentence 1 be a slangy version of this:

> 2. He was halfway ***through*** a bottle of wine.

which replaces "*into*" with "*through*"?

Comment: They’re about the same, yes.

Comment: I don't really think "slangy" is an appropriate word here. It's just that for this *exact* context, we're more likely to use ***through***. Conversely, *"We were halfway **into** the film when the projector broke down"* may actually be more likely than ***through***. Certainly if we replace ***halfway*** with ***half an hour***, the ***into*** version becomes *far* more likely to me. But it's all just idiomatic preference - "slanginess" (and indeed semantics) aren't really relevant.

Comment: I don't know if this is a common thing, but the use of *into* implies to me that the person set out with the goal of finishing the bottle in order to become drunk (along the lines of "he crawled into a bottle" -> *he purposely drank to excess in order to forget his troubles*); while the use of *through* would have no such implication, more likely meaning that he didn't realize how much or how quickly he'd been drinking, or that he'd been drinking (at a normal rate) for a long time.

Comment: @Hellion: You're quite right, which arguably implies I was wrong to say there are no *semantic* implications. But I think they only arise because we know that *through* would be more likely in OP's context, so we creatively look for any credible alternative meaning that might have caused the writer to use a different word. So at least *part* of the justification for your nuanced distinction doesn't so much lie in the specific word ***into*** - it's just *the fact that the more "normal" preposition wasn't used*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace "into" with "through" to get the same meaning.  It also sounds slightly less casual.